# 80s/90s sci-fi YA book about saving the world from aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, young-adult

I am looking for a young adult book that was probably written in in the late 80s or 90s. In this book, a boy who met an alien, and that alien was trying to stop a scarier alien from destroying the world. But when the second alien figures out what the kid is trying to do, he initiates something that makes the boy start to slowly disintegrate, which is only signaled because he starts to bleed from under his nails.

Comment: Can you recall any other details?

Comment: I think the enemy alien was his classmate. But this is a different book from Aliens Ate My Homework, which has some similar elements but is less goofy.